# What is the reason behind this type of error?

Tags: c#, android-layout, xamarin.android

I'm getting below error when running the app after deploy.

```
"Android.Content.Res.Resources+NotFoundException: File res/drawable-mdpi-  v4/submenulistitem_background_top.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f02008e"
```

The code giving error is as:

```
txtListItem.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.SubMenuListItem_Background_Top);
```

I have the xml resource present in the drawable folders and also the entry for resource is present in resource.designer.cs file. The app is running fine for latest android devices, but giving this error in one of the old android device. The older device have api v10.

When drawable are given in *.axml as - android:background="@drawable/something" for v10 device, it finds and draws the UI, but when set drawable programmatically, then this type of error occurs, the code for adapter is as:

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Greenlee.Ethernet.AndroidDevice
{
  public class SubMenuListViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<string>
  {
    string[] items;
    Activity context;

    public SubMenuListViewAdapter(Activity context, string[] items) : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override string this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Length; }
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView; // re-use an existing view, if one is available
        TextView txtListItem = null;

        if (view == null) // otherwise create a new one
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.SubMenuListItemLayout, null);

        txtListItem = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.text1);

        if (position == 0)
        {
            txtListItem.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.SubMenuListItem_Background_Top); // error line, I checked with setBackgroundDrawable() method too, but no luck.
        }
        else if (items.Length - position == 1)
        {
            txtListItem.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.submenulistitembackgroundbottom);
        }
        else
        {
            txtListItem.SetBackgroundResource(Resource.Drawable.submenulistitembackground);
        }

        txtListItem.Text = items[position];
        return view;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: most-likely that device is using a dpi setting you don't have resources for, where it won't auto-scale a different version of the resource.  Based on the message you need something in the drawable-mdpi folder.

Comment: no luck, I have all the *.axml files present in all of the drawable directories. I cleaned the Resource.designer.cs file and rebuild the project, this also didn't helped. Thanks for reply @escape-llc

Comment: I solved the issue, I was missing one of the dimens value  referenced in layout file. But the error message was not friendly, which caused the confusion.